# Persistence.xml settings for hibernate and mysql says "No Persistence provider for EntityManager"

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a simple ORM program, using JPA and hibernate. I want to write it as portable as possible, so that when I provide a different persistence provider, only the persistence.xml file has to be changed. Following is the persistence.xml file I have.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="JPA_Project" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>
            Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
        </description>

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <class>com.tutorial.prj.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpatestdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Is the above persistence.xml file correct? When I run the program through eclipse, it says `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JPA_Project`

I have added the hibernate jars and mysql connector to the build path. What is the issue here? I have also seen a different type of persistence.xml file used on the internet as follows.

```
<persistence-unit name="my_schema">
    ... classes ...

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://URL:3306/my_schema"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="my_user"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="my_pass"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.nombre" value="my_schema" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here the property names are different from the ones I have used, what is the reason behind using these property names? Which should be the correct persistence.xml file for easier portability.

Note that this is not a web application. Is this problem appearing because it is not a web application? Can hibernate be used in a local desktop application? My persistence.xml file is stored in `\JPA_Project\src\META-INF` folder.

Comment: have you added `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency in your pom ?

Comment: I have not used Maven. I want to build this program without maven

Comment: Okay, so have you added `hibernate-entitymanager` related jar package ?

Comment: Nope. Should I add it?

Comment: @DesirePRG I guess class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence exist in the class path

Comment: Yes you need to add it. try it then post that have you resolved it ?

Comment: That problem is resolved after adding the jar, the table gets created but the values does not get inserted

Comment: So there's now some other coding issue. for that you need to add another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add jar package of `hiberntare-entitymanager`.

If you are using maven then you need to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you also address the second part of the question? about the other persistence.xml file

Comment: if you are talking about using hibernate desktop application(swing) then yes we can. or if I am missing something then let me know.

Comment: in the second persistence.xml file, instead of javax.persistence.jdbc.url  hibernate.connection.url is used. and few other property names are also different. what is the reason to use those property names?